# Brackets For Function Name

Tags: function, lua

Hey guys This is my first lua script, its a speedhack for a game (offline dont worry) and i keep getting an error with the function name, im not sure what to fix exactly.

```
function Speedhack1()
boost = 1.5
if (readbytes{'[_speed]') `- nil) then
writeFloat ('[_speed]+DC', readFloat('[_speed]+DC')*boost)
writeFloat ('[_speed]+E0', readFloat('[_speed]+E0')*boost)
writeFloat ('[_speed]+E4', readFloat('[_speed]+E4')*boost)
end
end
createHotkey(speedhack1, VK_UP)

function Speedhack2()
boost = 0.5
if (readbytes{'[_speed]') `- nil) then
writeFloat ('[_speed]+DC', readFloat('[_speed]+DC')*boost)
writeFloat ('[_speed]+E0', readFloat('[_speed]+E0')*boost)
writeFloat ('[_speed]+E4', readFloat('[_speed]+E4')*boost)
end
end
createHotkey(speedhack2, VK_DOWN)
```

This is the error it throws back at me when trying to execute:

Error in script  Script  1  : [string "function Speedhack1()
..."]:3: '}' expected near ')'

when i try to replace ")" with "}" it just yells at me the reverse. very confused lol

Comment: Why did you tag this #assembly?

Comment: sorry i was just putting tags its been removed

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the curly braces in "readbytes{". Could you please try to replace that with "("?

Comment: dude thank you so much im such a goof

Comment: Ive got a new error the lua script runs but upon using my hotkeys it returns this error

"attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value"

Answer (score 0):

The code that causes the error here is in line 3

> `` if (readbytes{'[_speed]') `- nil) then ``

In Lua the argument you pass for a function must have an opening and ending of `(` and `)` respectively. Therefore as you can note in line 3 the argument you have passed for `readbytes` has an opening of `{` which is the cause of the error. In order to resolve this replace `{` with `(`